# How to use gesture to move large image in a view using swift

Tags: xcode

I can able to do pinch zoom using pinch gesture using swift. But after image enlarges, i can't able view the which is out of view. (i.e)can't able to move image around the screen. Can any one help me?

My code:

```
@IBAction func scaleImage(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view!.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale)

    sender.scale = 1
  }
```

I need to view full image after zooming it.

Comment: you have to do it with scrollView!

Comment: ya...but i dont know how to do it..can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ScrollView and add image on scrollView

```
class ViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{
     @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView! 
     @IBOutlet var scroll: UIScrollView! 

     override func viewDidLoad() { 
     super.viewDidLoad() 

     scroll.maximumZoomScale=4; 
     scroll.minimumZoomScale=1.0; 
     scroll.bounces=true; 
     scroll.bouncesZoom=true; 
     scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height); 
     scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=true; 
     scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=true; 
     scroll.delegate=self;//assigning delegate 
     self.scroll.addSubview(imageView); 
     self.view.addSubview(scroll); 
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { 
           super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. 
     } 


    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
    {
         return self.imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: comment if have any query

Comment: The above is in objective-c. But am using swift. In swift, how to call delegate method?

Comment: scrollView.delegate = self

Comment: Type view controller does not conform to protocol UIScrollviewDelegate

Comment: And excepted declaration in add delegate method.

Comment: did you add ScrollViewDelegate??

Comment: excepted declaration ?? or expected declaration??

Comment: expected declaration.

Comment: at which line ?? can you please write code here?? so i can help you

Comment: In add delegate method line -(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:

Comment: may be you are missing to complete bracket ??did you check for this??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64673/discussion-between-saurabh-prajapati-and-divya).